# AngularJS json url not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, controller

Can someone please have a look at my js fiddle, I'm trying to get angular JS to display the list in the JSON file but I cannot get it working.

Very new to angular JS and trying to figure it out as I go

https://jsfiddle.net/2zumpvy9/

```
<body ng-app="DraftApp">
  <div class="main" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="each" ng-repeat="player in players">
        {{ player.Player }}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>


var app = angular.module('DraftApp', []);

app.factory('players', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('http://redraft.comxa.com/test.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      return data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      return err;
    });
}]);


app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'players', function($scope, players) {
  players.success(function(data) {
    $scope.players = data;
  });
}]);
```

Comment: You're having CORS issues:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://redraft.comxa.com/test.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access`.

Comment: So do I need to host the JSON file somewhere else? I had been using codecademy up till now to learn and this is the first time I'm going out of that environment and it's not as easy as they make it look -_-

Comment: Also you fiddle is not working.

Comment: Security restrictions in browsers will not let you load the JSON file from a different domain. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Yeah I know my fiddle isn't working :p that's what I'm trying to get help with. I think it's a combination of not having <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>, my json file and not understanding fiddle

Comment: Thanks Daniel, so if I try to run it off my shoddy free website where the json file is held it should be okay?

Comment: @HJB77 can you check my answer? I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

However, you can use the `https://crossorigin.me/` service.

Then, you should request: «https://crossorigin.me/http://redraft.comxa.com/test.json». Finally, this can be easily used in your AngularJS code.

I've made a demo, using an AngularJS Service and Controller.

```js
var app = angular.module("DraftApp", []);

app.factory("players", ["$http",
  function($http) {
    return $http.get("https://crossorigin.me/http://redraft.comxa.com/test.json")
      .success(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
      .error(function(err) {
        return err;
      });
  }
]);

app.controller("HomeController", ["$scope", "players",
  function($scope, players) {
    players.success(function(data) {
      $scope.players = data;
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="DraftApp">
  <div class="main" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="each" ng-repeat="player in players">
        {{ player.Player }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, that's exactly what I was after. I'm at work now but will have a play around when i get home. Appreciate the help